# Trouble playing a video with AVFoundation

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, avfoundation, avplayer

I am trying to create an AVPlayer that will display a video file.

This is the code I have so far:

```
- (IBAction) player {
       NSURL* m = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Cache" withExtension:@"mov"];
       AVURLAsset* asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:m options:nil];
       AVPlayerItem* item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
       AVPlayer* p = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:item];
       self.player = p;
       AVPlayerLayer* lay = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:p];
       lay.frame = CGRectMake(10, 76, 303, 265);
       [self.view.layer addSublayer:lay];
       [p play];
}
```

I have already linked to `AVFoundation.framework` and `CoreMedia.framework` and I have imported `<AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>`.

First of all, I am getting an error that says `property 'player' not found on object of type 'ViewController*` (for the line `self.player = p;`). What do I need to do to get this to run?

Also after the error is fixed, will this code work correctly to display the video?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your viewController obviously does not contain such instance variable.

To fix that issue, add the following to your viewController header file (.h):

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVPlayer *player;
```

Then add the following to your viewController implementation file (.m):

```
@synthesize player;
```

The first step will ensure that your viewController object actually owns an instance variable named player. The second step will create a matching setter and getter.

Comment: That fixed that issue. However, the video is still not displaying.  I am trying to run this in the simulator. Any other ideas?